# Regarding "f-strings now support = for quick and easy debugging", how to print `f'{array[{i=}]=}'` with index also "="-expanded?

Tags: python, arrays, printing

For simplicity, we have an array

```
 >>> arr = [1,2,3]
 >>> for i in range(len(arr)):
 >>>     print(f'{arr[i]=}')
```

we get

```
 >>> arr[i]=1
 >>> arr[i]=2
 >>> arr[i]=3
```

Would it be possible to expand to output like this

```
 >>> arr[i=0]=1
 >>> arr[i=1]=2
 >>> arr[i=2]=3
```

or

```
 >>> arr[0]=1
 >>> arr[1]=2
 >>> arr[2]=3
```

The real practice is to debug the code and check the array with >1000 elements.
Neither `print(f'{arr[{i=}]=}')` nor `print(f'{arr[{i}]=}')` can work for me.

Comment: You could print them separately `print(f'{i=} {arr[i]=}')`

Comment: `f'arr[{i=}]={arr[i]}'`

Comment: Sure you could do so or in other workarounds. It might be a convenience to be compact.

Comment: I think it is not possible directly, because one expression (in curly braces) -> one value to print. Consider e.g. `f"{sin(n*pi/2)=}"` where `n` value should be printed, but `pi` value should not. The only good solution is to give the format string explicitly whenever you want anyhing more than a simple debugging aid.

Answer (score 2):

I get the idea, but isn't it much more readable to just do:

```
for i, x in enumerate(arr):
    print(f'arr[{i}]={x}')
```